# matplotlib-draw vintage cure for specific field based on the range

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have data set like

```
date           Status

1/8/2018       30+

1/8/2018       20

16/10/2017      31+

1/2/2018        31+

4/7/2018        31+ 

...             10

3/6/2018        31+
...            ....
```

I want to Create a vintage curve of 31+. how do I draw the curve?
I tried to like this, I know its right way to plot

```
import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import seaborn as sns


df = pd.read_csv('sample_data.csv')

for i in df['status']:

    if i >= 30:

       sns.distplot((df['status']),bins=10);
       plt.show()
```

This is what I get as output,

[image]

How do I specify the range? I am new for data visualization.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First filter your dataframe:

```
DF=df[df['status']>30]
```

than plot:

```
sns.distplot(DF['status'],bins=10);
plt.show()
```